# How to prove this prime counting method is correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem: given $n$ and the set $P$ is primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$, count primes less than or equal to $n$.

Solution: 
let $B =\{b_i= \lfloor n/\displaystyle\prod_{t \in a_i} t\rfloor,\ a_i\in 2^P,\ b_i = -b_i \ if\ |a_i| \in 2\mathbb Z +1\},\\ $
$\displaystyle\quad\sum_{b\in B} b + |P| - 1$ is number of primes less than or equal to $n$.

How to prove this prime counting method is correct?

Here's the  Python vesion:

```
from primesieve import *
import math
from itertools import chain, combinations
import operator
import functools


def Pi(n):    
    p = primes(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n) + 0.00001) - 1)   
    a = []
    for i in chain.from_iterable(combinations(p, r) for r in range(1, len(p)+1)):
        t = math.floor(n/functools.reduce(operator.mul, i, 1))
        if len(i) & 1 == 1:
            t *= -1
        a.append(t)
    return n + sum(a) + len(p) - 1 

print(Pi(1000))
# out put: 168
```

Comment: What is $a_i$ ? The elements of $A$ ?

Comment: Seems to be something like inclusion-exclusion, but I am not sure it will work for $4$ factors. Did you check ?

Comment: @Peter print(Pi(100))  get $32$, there's something wrong.

Comment: @Peter Bug fixed.

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [How to prove this prime counting method is correct?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/346731)

Comment: The MO post has been closed as off-topic.

Comment: Dear miket , your question is unclear to many. You really need to explain better and define your symbols and stuff well. The code may help some but techniqually is not math language. Plz make an edit so we can understand.

Comment: @mick Let's take n=10,P={2,3} as an example, 
 number of primes less than or equal to 10 is 10 - floor(10/2) - floor(10/3) + length(P) = 10 - 5 - 3 + 2 = 4, is this very simple?

Comment: In that case no. It will fail for large integers. Notice 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/11 is more than 1.

Comment: Also see Mertens constant. Using (1 -1/2)(1-1/3)... is not very efficient

Comment: @mick  $floor(10/2)=5$ is remove $2,4,6,8,10$, do you see that?

Comment: Yes miket I see that.